# jQuery Дождаться выполнение 2-ух animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

Нужно после окончания 2ух анимаций, сменить значение переменной.

```
 old_elem.animate({
        top: curr_elem.css('top'),
        left: curr_elem.css('left')
    }, 100, function(){//действия после анимации
    });

    curr_elem.animate({
        top: old_elem.css('top'),
        left: old_elem.css('left')
    }, 100, function(){//действия после анимации
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант - через [Promise](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise):

```js
$(() => {
  $('input').on('click', function(e){
    Promise.all([
      new Promise((res, rej) => $('#one').animate({fontSize: '20pt'}, 200, _ => res())),
      new Promise((res, rej) => $('#two').animate({fontSize: '30pt'}, 300, _ => res()))
    ]).then(_ => $(this).val('Done!'))
  });
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id='one'>One</div>
<div id='two'>Two</div>
<input type='button' value='Run' />
```